# how to use isset in yii criteria

Tags: php, yii

is there anyway to use isset in yii **criteria**?

i have two tables named equipment and supply.. They are pretty much the same except that equipment has this field named stock_no. Now I have a search function to show equipment or supply records depending on a dropdown.

Basically what I want is to use if isset to **check** if *stack_no* **exists** to prove that it is **from** equipment **table**.

```
    if($this->itemType=="Equipment"){
            $criteria->isset('stock_no', true ); // what may be the correct way to check if this column is existing? 
    }

    if($this->itemType=="Supply"){

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exequte a this query.

```
SELECT count(*) exist FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
                      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourSchema' 
                      AND TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable' 
                      AND COLUMN_NAME = 'stock_no'
```

This return 1 or 0 if exist this column on the table specified.